# Have not inserted google fonts link in <head> tag, but I can still use Roboto?

Tags: html, css

I am using Roboto font and decided to delete the google fonts link in the head tag to see how would my page look with the default font, however, after refreshing the page nothing changed.

Then I decided to delete the `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;` from my CSS file and the font turned to default. Then I added it again and it turned to Roboto once again.

I cleared my cache and cookies and refreshed the page with Ctrl+Shift+R but the font was still Roboto.

I assume I can't use Roboto without google fonts link in my head, right? Despite that I still see Roboto.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use make use of certain fonts, without the use of Google fonts,

This isnt really a question and will surely be closed, Please ask more constructive questions next time.

Comment: So Roboto is one of them? Then what's the point using Google fonts for Roboto? Do only specific browsers support Roboto by default?